# Open filename via variable in binary mode Python

Tags: python, file, pickle

I'm trying to figure out how I can open a file via a pathvariable in binary mode.

So basically I want instead of:

```
open(b'picklefile.p', 'wb')
```

this

```py
path = /picklefiles/picklefile.p

open(b'path', 'wb')
```

I tried to solve this by leaving the b out but apparently, things go wrong. I wasn't able to find a way that allows me to use a variable as every available example uses the direct path, am I overlooking something or is it not possible so I need to convert it somehow?

Comment: The variable name is `path`, not `b'path'` or `'path'`. And to assign a string to path you use `path = '/picklefiles/picklefile.p'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b` is basically calling the `bytes()` function on the string.
more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6269785/7359978)

```
>>> path = "test.txt"
>>> f = open(bytes(path, "ascii"), "r")
>>> f.readline()
'testing testing \n'
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to assign the string name of a path to a variable and then use that variable:

```py
path = b'/picklefiles/picklefile.p'

file = open(path, 'wb')
```